# How to properly pass form content with special characters to SQL Server nvarchar field from PHP/Linux app?

Tags: php, sql-server, nvarchar

I have a web application on a Ubuntu/PHP7/nginx stack that for data reporting purposes passes data to a SQL Server 2008 database. I'm using the php7.0-sybase PDO package to connect to MSSQL. I use a prepared statement call to a stored procedure to insert the data. The fields on the SQL Server side are nvarchar fields of various lengths.  The issue: form content from the web application with special characters (newlines, accented letters, etc) shows as all garbled (Chinese-esque) characters once inserted into the database. I suspect it is an encoding issue, but I haven't been able to pinpoint what exactly that issue is as I'm not knowledgeable in this area.

If I test doing an insert directly on SQL Server using T-SQL, the text with special characters shows correctly.

If I dump the encoding of the text before I send it from the web app, it tells me it is ASCII, which should be compatible with UTF-8, correct? I've also tried explicitly converting it to UTF-8 before sending.

Is there something I need to set in the configuration of my db driver? Or maybe the driver just doesn't know how to properly handle this data?

As a note, we've experimented with sending this type of data to a varchar field, and the text appears correctly, so this is an issue specifically with the nvarchar data type.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, SQL Server does not support UTF-8 for stored data. The `nvarchar` data type corresponds to UTF-16.

Comment: Ah. Shows you what I know. I tried doing a manual conversion of one of the fields with special characters to UTF-16 encoding (using `iconv()` PHP function) before submitting to the data and that works. But, how do people writing PHP application usually handle this? Is there a way to get PHP to automatically pass fields this way or to have SQL Server convert them to appropriate coding?

Comment: I did more testing, and it appears the original source of the issue is the db library/driver. I tested my work on a different dev system with php5 and the php5-mssql package (which I think really just installs php5-sybase). When I use that library, the text with special characters is passed correctly and implicitly converted to nvarchar when inserted via the stored procedure, as one would expect. Likely I will end up explicitly encoding each value to UTF-16 before sending to ensure forward compatibility.

Comment: Normally, one would expect db libraries to become better with time, not worse :) If I were you, I would try to switch to the latest version and forget the issue completely (assuming it doesn't fail in other cases, of course).

Comment: Well, yes. I should have said "short-term forward compatibility" - i.e. ensure my app still works if the production system gets upgraded to php7 before the php7.0-sybase package is improved.

Comment: Or better yet, now that Microsoft is developing a Linux port of SQL Server, with luck you will eventually have proper drivers directly from them.